# Android content resolver query placeholder integer

Tags: android, arguments, selection

I am trying to run a simple query on the android Browser Content Provider. The bookmarks are mixed with history items, so to get the bookmarks only one needs to select "Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK = 1". Using

```
String mSelectionClause = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 1";
```

with

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, null, mSelectionClause, null, null);
```

works fine. But all my attempts to get the same result with a placeholder fail:

```
String mSelectionClause = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = ?";
```

The query:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, null, mSelectionClause, mSelectinArgs, null);
```

returns an empty Cursor in all these cases:

```
mSelectionArgs[0] = "1"
mSelectionArgs[0] = '1'
mSelectionArgs[0] = String.valueOf(1)
mSelectionArgs[0] = Integer.toString(1)
mSelectionArgs[0] = 1 + "" (idea picked up on this site)
```

Am I doing something wrong or should I give up the hope of using a placeholder?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android database API was designed for Strings and not Integers. Some people says it was a mistake in the design of the API.

Anyway, in your example `String mSelectionClause = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 1";` you are using an integer (= 1). This is the best and only way to deal with Integers. It is also safe to do so. If you were to use strings, your second solution would be the safest.

Comment: Thanks. So the rule of thumb would be "use placeholders when database field is a string, for other types value directly in the selection clause"? 

If I may take this a bit further, what would be a good way of avoiding the hard-coded value? Can a constant defined by the provider be used in the clause? Or a resource string?

Comment: If you are talking purely about code design, yes, if you know the value of Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK is always 1, you could use a constant or even writing the whole line as a constant (the mSelectionClause in your case). If you have a lot of queries with the same condition on the BOOKMARK, the SelectionBuilder class may help you refactorized your code and make the selection simpler : https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/src/com.example.android.common/db/SelectionBuilder.html